# Add an array exception in if statement

Tags: java, arrays, if-statement

i have one array with the following values [1,2,3,4,5]

i want to print a message when my array hold the values 1,2,3. How do I do this? :)

```
int[] myarray = new int[] {1,2,3,4,5};
if ( ... ) {
    System.out.println("This array is on fire!");
```

I suppose you could do like this:

```
if (myarray[0]==1 && myarray[1]==2 && myarray[2]==3) {
     .....
    }
```

but if it's possible, i will avoid this. I wish to avoid the position in the array being a factor.

Comment: the values you want to check (1,2,3 in your case) must be the 1st, 2nd and 3rd element of your array?

Comment: nah the position should not be important

Answer (score 3):

Unluckily `Arrays.asList(myarray)` doesnt work for `int`, as noted in the comments, i forgot...
So use `Integer` as Array-Type or convert first in an `Integer-List`:

```
   List<Integer> intList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    for (int index = 0; index < myarray.length; index++)
    {
        intList.add(myarray[index]);
    }
```

as pointed out [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1073919/how-to-convert-int-into-listinteger-in-java), then follow the old solution with this list:

```
if (intList.contains(1)  && intList.contains(2) && intList.contains(3)) {
...
}
```

Comment: where do u get the method .contains? :)

Comment: @jk2 `Arrays.asList` when applied to an `int[]` returns a `List<int[]>` which is probably not what you want.

Comment: ah, thanks. i forgot to import ArrayList and List interface, thats why it did not work.

Answer (score 2):

You could write a utility method as follows (**assumes the array is sorted before hand please see the update if it's not the case**):

```
public static boolean checkIfOnFire(int[] arr, int... nums) {
    for(int n : nums) {
        if(Arrays.binarySearch(arr, n) < 0) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Test with:

```
int[] myarray = new int[] {1,2,3,4,5};

System.out.println(checkIfOnFire(myarray, 1, 2, 3));
System.out.println(checkIfOnFire(myarray, 1, 2, 7));
```

Prints:

```
true
false
```

**Update**:

Since I am using the [`Arrays.binarySearch`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#binarySearch%28int%5b%5d,%20int%29). The input array to the `checkIfOnFire` method has to be sorted as it is in your example.

But if your array might not be sorted then `checkIfOnFire` has to be modified as follows:

```
public static boolean checkIfOnFire(int[] arr, int... nums) {
    //make a copy of the original array
    int[] copyArr = new int[arr.length];
    System.arraycopy(arr, 0, copyArr, 0, arr.length);
    //sort the copy
    Arrays.sort(copyArr);
    for(int n : nums) {
        if(Arrays.binarySearch(copyArr, n) < 0) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: This assumes the initial array is sorted.

Comment: +1 even with sort, this way is still faster then the asList() than 3x contains. with QuickSort/mergeSort, checking 3 candidates in this way is O(nlogn)+3 x O(logn), with list, is 3x O(n). and during the binarySearch, there is still room to optimize, e.g. found 1, then next search for (2), just taking the subarray after element 1 (assuming ascending sorted). of course, it depends if performance is critical for OP.

Answer (score 1):

It ain't pretty, but if you wrote something like this:

```
public static boolean containsAll(int[] arrayToTest, int... values) {
    return asList(arrayToTest).containsAll(asList(values));     
}

public static List<Integer> asList(int[] values) {
    List<Integer> asList = new ArrayList<Integer>(values.length);
    for (int intVal : values) {
        asList.add(intVal);
    }
    return asList;
}
```

You can then call it like this:

```
int[] myarray = new int[] {1,2,3,4,5};
boolean result = containsAll(myarray, 1, 2, 3);
```

Comment: `Arrays.asList(arrayToTest)` will return a `List<int[]>`.

Comment: Thanks, I just realized that reading your other comment.  Edited with the fix.

Answer (score 0):

Longer solution, but requires only one pass. Can be easily customized to check for any number of items.

```
public boolean onFire(int array[])
{
    boolean found1 = false;
    boolean found2 = false;
    boolean found3 = false;
    for (int i : array) {
        if(i==1)
        {
            found1= true;
            continue;
        }
        if(i==2)
        {
            found2= true;
            continue;
        }
        if(i==3)
        {
            found3= true;
            continue;
        }
        if(found1&&found2&&found3)
            return true;
    }
    if(found1&&found2&&found3)
         return true;
    return false;       
}
```

Comment: Wow.  This is a smorgasboard of code smells.  Strange method names, overspecialization, unnecessary use of `continue` when `else` would work, redundant success checks, checking for a boolean instead of returning a boolean value.  Did I miss any?

Answer (score 0):

If your wanted `int`s are non-negative, small, and dense; and you don't care about the order they appear in `ints`, then:

```
BitSet wanted = new BitSet();
wanted.set(1);
wanted.set(2);
wanted.set(3);

for (int i : ints) {
  wanted.clear(i);
}

boolean hasAll = wanted.cardinality() == 0;
```

If you do care about order, then you probably want to test whether one array is a sub-sequence of another: [Get the list of index in subsequence matching](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3094779/get-the-list-of-index-in-subsequence-matching)

Answer (score 0):

To find the elements in any order in the array, first add the elements you're interested to a hash map. Then see if they are in the array.

Runtime: O(m) to add to map, to iterate over array O(n), m < n. Total O(n).

In the code below, call main() to run the sample I wrote.

```
 Map<Integer,Boolean> lookFor = new HashMap<Integer,Boolean>();

 void main(){
    int[] array = new int[] {1,2,3,4,5};
    addMeaningfulValues();
    System.out.println( arrayHasValues(lookFor, array) );
 }

 void addMeaningfulValues(){
    lookFor.put(1,false);
    lookFor.put(2,false);
    lookFor.put(3,false);
 }

 boolean arrayHasValues(Map<Integer,Boolean> values, int [] array){
    //mark entries found in array
    for (int i=0; i<array.length; i++){
        if (values.containsKey(array[i])){
            values.put(array[i], true);
        }
    }

    //go over map entries and see if they have all been found in the array
    for (Boolean crtValue: values.values()){
        if (!crtValue){
            return false;
        }
    }

    return true;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Put it in a Collection or List and do a contains for each item you are looking for.

```
Integer[] myarray = {1,2,3,4,5};
List<Integer> intList = Arrays.asList(myArray);

if (intList.contains(1) && intList.contains(2) && intList.contains(3))
    // print your message
```

Comment: I tried this:
Integer[] myarray={0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0};
List<Integer> myarray2 = Arrays.asList(myarray);

It did not work, any ideas? I get error lines under "List" and Arrays". I forgot to import something?

Answer (score 0):

Make use of the [containsAll](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#containsAll(java.util.Collection)) method in the Collection interface.

```
Collection<Integer> coll = new ArrayList<Integer>();
Collection<Integer> test = new ArrayList<Integer>();

for( int i=1; i<=5; i++)
    coll.add(i);

test.add(1);
test.add(2);
test.add(3);

System.out.println(coll.containsAll(test));
```

Answer (score 0):

Due to wide use of collections java considered as collection is a framework and each collections consisting of a method contains(Object o) to check whether an element is existing or not in a collection.

1. so first we can convert the int[] array to a List

   ```
   List<Integer> list=new ArrayList<Integer>();
           int[] myarray = new int[] {1,2,3,4,5};
           for(int i=0;i<myarray.length;i++)
           {
               list.add(myarray[i]);           
           }
   ```
2. please use list.contains(Object o) to check whether its existing or not

   ```
    for(Integer i:list)
           {
               if(list.contains(1)&&list.contains(2)&&list.contains(3))
               {
                   flag=true;
                   break;
               }

           }
   ```

and check the complete code below

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import java.util.List;



public class Test {


    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        boolean flag=false;
        List<Integer> list=new ArrayList<Integer>();
        int[] myarray = new int[] {1,2,3,4,5};
        for(int i=0;i<myarray.length;i++)
        {
            list.add(myarray[i]);           
        }
        for(Integer i:list)
        {
            if(list.contains(1)&&list.contains(2)&&list.contains(3))
            {
                flag=true;
                break;
            }

        }

        if(flag)
        {
            System.out.println("yes contain");

        }
        else
            System.out.println("NO");

    }

}
```